# Error whilst publishing Sitefinity4 project

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-4

I'm trying to deploy a Sitefinity 4 project. I have the main web app project, and two external class libraries. I've tried to publish, and ive tried using a web deployment project, however both times it complains about missing references, like:

The type or namespace name 'Sitefinity' does not exist in the namespace 'Telerik' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

It is always referring to a line of code in one of the class libraries. Do i need to add the assemblies to the app.config file?

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Josh recently wrote two blog posts for installing Sitefinity on IIS. Maybe those could help you. Depending on whether you are deploying on IIS6 or IIS7:

[Installing Sitefinity on IIS6](http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/joshmorales/posts/11-02-23/installing_sitefinity_4_on_iis_6.aspx)
[Installing Sitefinity on IIS7](http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/joshmorales/posts/11-02-22/installing_sitefinity_4_on_iis_7.aspx)